# AngularJS : What is the right way to close dropdown/popover element on outside mouse click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, popover

Where should I set listener for outside click if I want to create directive for popover/tooltip/dropdown that should be close after this event?

Answer (score 3):

We created a directive for that that's pretty simple:

```
'use strict';

yourmodule.directive('clickOutside', function($parse, $document){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      var fn = $parse(attr.clickOutside);
      $document.bind('click', clickOutsideHandler);
      element.bind('remove', function () {
        $document.unbind('click', clickOutsideHandler);
      });

      function clickOutsideHandler(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var targetParents = $(event.target).parents();
        var inside = targetParents.index(element) !== -1;
        var on     = event.target === element[0];
        var outside = !inside && !on;

        if (outside) scope.$apply(function() {
          fn(scope, {$event:event});
        });
      }

    }
  };
});
```

Use it like this:

```
<div click-outside="handleClick($event)">...</div>
```

Comment: This requires jquery in $(event.target).parents(). what about pure angular solution

Comment: This is not really doable in "pure" Angular. To solve this problem, you need to access API's that are lower-level than Angular.You could of course replace the jQuery calls with pure DOM code.